# Insertar una consulta MySQL en un script

Tags: php

Tengo este script

```js
var futuredate=new cdtime("countdowncontainer", "2016-10-28 00:00:00")
futuredate.displaycountdown("days", formatresults)
var currentyear=new Date().getFullYear()
```

y necesito que la fecha no sea escrita si no una consulta a base de datos MySQL.
Es decir, que tenga el valor de `$programar_antes_de['end']`

De la siguiente consulta:

```php
<?php
$programar_antes_de_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_GANTS 
                                       . " where xxxx and xxxx and xxxx ");

$programar_antes_de = tep_db_fetch_array($programar_antes_de_query);

echo  '' . tep_date_short($programar_antes_de['end']) . '';
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo, ¿querés inyectar el valor de una variable de PHP en el código de JavaScript? ¿Algo como `cdtime("countdowncontainer", "<?php echo $programar_antes_de['end'] ?>")` ?

Comment: si exacto tengo un script que es el siguiente var futuredate=new cdtime("countdowncontainer", "2016-10-28 00:00:00") y necesito que la fecha sea una query insertado de mysql, algo como lo que muestras pero asi como esta escrito ya lo intente pero no funciona

Comment: ¿Por qué no funciona? ¿Qué imprime?

Comment: muy agradecido ya funciona, quizas omiti alguna comilla, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada! Voy a votar para cerrar la pregunta porque era un error tipográfico, y sentite en total libertad de hacer una nueva pregunta si surge algún otro problema